# error: expected identifier while compiling

Tags: identifier, greedy

This is code which I wrote for learning of new function "round".

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <cs50.h>

 int main(void);
 float a = 0;
 float b = 0;
{

    do 
     {
         // Here we will ask fo the change.
         printf("How much change do I owe?\n");
         float a = GetFloat();
     }
     while (a <= 0);
    {
        // Use of new function round which will round off the float and conver it to int or any specified number format.
        float b = (int)round( a * 100);
        printf("%f\n", b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it gives the following error

greedy.c:6:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [greedy] Error 1

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: the syntax of the code have problems

Comment: I am writing code for greedy pset1, so was trying new function called "Round".  What could be possible syntax problem?

Comment: then you want to define a new function ?

Comment: No my function has no problem its fine but the error that says "expected identifier or '(' { ^ 1 error generated." is what I don't understand. It happens several time with other codes to.

Comment: "No my function has no problem its fine" - the fact that the compiler is spitting out errors means it's not fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look you have some syntax and logical problems :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float a = 0;
    do 
     {
         // Here we will ask fo the change.
         printf("How much change do I owe?\n");
         scanf("%f",&a);
         // Use of new function round which will round off the float and conver it to int or any specified number format.
         a = (int)(a * 100);
         printf("%f", a);
     }
     while (a <= 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed... Please check new edited question. But still, problem prevails.

Comment: you entered exactly the same code as I wrote ?

Comment: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found

Comment: I've edited it , try it again

Comment: greedy.1.c:2:1: error: unknown type name 'using'
using namespace std;
^
greedy.1.c:2:16: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
using namespace std;
               ^
               ;
2 errors generated.

Comment: oops ! I forget to remove `using namespace std;` :)) try it again

Comment: Your programme runs fine!  Why my programme won't run, check question i have edited it.

Comment: you have syntactical problems , like you can't define something between `int main()` and its `{` , If you want to define global variable it should be outside of the main , like this : `float a = 0; float b = 0;int main(void){//your code here}` , the second problem is if you defined sth like `float a = 0` once , you shouldn't define it again , for using it , it is enough to use `a` instead of `float a` , and sth like these , I think you must review syntax of the code ...

Comment: if it was true , mark my answer as true from the top left of my answer in the site